# One time purchase with expiration

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I would like to let users purchase a good for 3 months for one time.

In subscriptions, even the user can cancel a subscription, since the cancellation of purchases is not possible inside application and the way to cancel a subscription is not straight-forward i think this would return us with a lot of user complaint due to forgotten subscription fees.

Managed product purchases are permanent so they don't work in my case.

Is there a way to make one time purchases with expiry date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such products out of the box. You have to implement it in your backend. You may use managed product and handle expiration date manually in the app with synchronization with your server.

You may try to hack it without backend comparing purchase date and correct current time (some trusted time server).